# Center logo and nav links vertically in header

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have just started my website, and I am currently working on the header/navigation bar. I've got it looking how I want, however the one thing I can't figure out, is how to centre the logo and hyperlinks vertically in the header?

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"></a></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">ABOUT ME</a></li>
          <li><a href="">PROJECTS</a></li>
          <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: #F4F4F4;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/**********************************
HEADING/NAVIGATION
***********************************/

li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 25px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
  background: #5BBB9B;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
}
```

I have tried using `vertical-alignment: middle;`, however this didn't work.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try this: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/14/justified-and-vertically-centered-header-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
display:table;
height:100%;
```

for the parent and

```
 display: table-cell;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: middle;
```

and check out this awesome article:
https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/